# Specific word choice in URL title is causing a 404 error on a page. Can anyone help?

Tags: channel-entries, structure, 404, url-title, title

I'm working in EE3 and have just come up against a problem that I've never experienced before and I'm really hoping someone can help.

I have created a page with the URL `/destination-reports`. When I go to the page on the front end I get a Not Found 404 error. However when I remove the word destination and the URL becomes `/reports`, the page loads fine as expected. Could '`destination`' be a specialist term that triggers an error?

Any ideas on why it would it be doing this? It's left me a tad confused

Thanks

Comment: just out of curiosity, does using an underbar instead of a hyphen work?

Comment: I have just tried and had the same outcome. I've never had this happen before so I don't know where to start. What could be so special about 'destination'

Comment: Ok.  Sorry, I was just wondering if the problem is related to .htaccess setup. Also, are you using template routes?

Comment: No template routes are currently in place. I did think htacess at first but then thought not. I was thinking 'Destination' could be a trigger word of some kind

Comment: Doesn't appear to be a reserved word according to the latest documentation

https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/general/reserved_words.html

Comment: If I try random URL titles, normally they will redirect me to the homepage if they are unrecognisable....but the minute I start a URL with 'de' it kills the page

I could have a URL title of /d and it would redirect me, but it doesn't seem to like anything beginning with 'de'

It's driving me insane :)

Comment: Is it an nginx error by chance?

Comment: I'm not sure how I would test that. Could well be the case

Answer (score 3):

Finally resolved this. On a whim I decided to try the URL /en and that had the same effect too so that meant it had to be language related, with the original problem being with 'de'.

In my htaccess, which is where I started in the first place, I found a reference to a multi-lingual snippet, which included en|fr|es and wouldn't you know it....de. Removing the 'de' sorted the issue straight away.

Mild stupidity on my part as it was right under my nose but I hope that this may help someone in the future.

Comment: glad you found the issue.  Thank you for posting the resolution.